# Function to stop after counting to 6

Tags: vba, function, count, median

I have a function below counting values above a median value but it counts all values in A that are above the median. I need this to stop counting when it gets to 6. Any help would be great.

```
Function CountAbove(RangeToCountAbove As Range, _
                MedianOfLastGroup As Double) As Long

Dim i As Double
Dim rows As Double
Dim cCell As Range

CountAbove = 0

For Each cCell In RangeToCountAbove
If (cCell.Value > MedianOfLastGroup) Then
    CountAbove = CountAbove + 1
Else
Exit Function
End If
Next cCell

End Function
```

Comment: `If CountAbove = 6 Then ...`

Comment: Do you add that before the else because it asks for the next For then. I am having trouble knowing where to insert that statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Comintern wrote, put the condition `If CountAbove = 6` inside your `If`, as added in the edited code below:

```
Function CountAbove(RangeToCountAbove As Range, _
                MedianOfLastGroup As Double) As Long

Dim i As Double
Dim rows As Double
Dim cCell As Range

CountAbove = 0

For Each cCell In RangeToCountAbove
    If (cCell.Value > MedianOfLastGroup) Then
        CountAbove = CountAbove + 1
        If CountAbove = 6 Then Exit Function
    Else
        Exit Function
    End If

Next cCell

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. I was leaving out the "exit function part"

Comment: @user3018495 you're welcome, please accept my answer

Comment: Can i ask one more question, If i want the count to skip  If (cCell.Value = MedianOfLastGroup) and move onto the next row, could i add that into same function?

Comment: Not sure what do u mean ? What do you want the function to do ?

Comment: I want it to skip if a value is equal to the MedianOfLastGroup but continue to count because at the moment is stops the count.

Comment: i basically want the function to count values in A that are above values in B and if the value in A is equal to B then i need it to skip that value but don't reset the counter